# How to install django in miniconda?

Tags: django, virtualenv, miniconda

i want to develop django rest API in windows.
Due to some reason i have to use  **miniconda** in my system.
My project location is **c:/users/noman/dev/cardionic/** .

i create virtualenv '**env**' using miniconda which is created in **c:/user/noman/miniconda3/envs/env** instead of base folder. I activate my env using '**activate env**' and install django. I create **new django project** using 'django-admin startproject cardio' .

when i run '**python manage.py runserver**' it generates "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlparse'** "

i have done my best but could not resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Setup an environment
conda create — name django2 python>3.7

Switch to / Activate the environment
conda activate django2

Install Django — the default version was 2.2.1
conda install -v django

Encountered ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘sqlparse’ when running python manage.py runserver. This will resolved by `conda install sqlparse`.